# Python - Working with colun names in cursors with hyphens

Tags: python, database-cursor

Any advice for selecting columns in a cursor when the db column names are poorly designed with hypens in them.  I agree the column's names with hyphens are a poor design but this was set up this way 10 years ago by someone else.    Here is an example where the field `time_offer_changed` works fine but `sellker-sku` does not.  I can select them by the their raw position - `row[6]` but would like to find something a bit easier to follow for someone who might touch this code later

```
cursor = db.cursor()  # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_inventory_data WHERE `ain`=%s AND `user`=%s", (AIN, SellerId)) 
db.commit()

for row in cursor.fetchall():
     r = reg(cursor, row)
     sku_time=r.time_offer_changed.  #works fne !!!!
     sku_seller_sku=r.seller-sku.    #no good !!!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the cursor to return a dictionary and access it via `r['seller-sku']` or if that's not possible/desirable then you can always use `sku_seller_sku = getattr(r, 'seller-sku')`